# Can't perform Helmert transformation in Proj.4

Tags: gdal, proj

I'm trying to convert a point from one SRS to another using proj4 strings and GDAL. My origin SRS uses Helmert transformation to convert point to EPSG:2229 so I tried to use pipeline operator (https://proj4.org/operations/pipeline.html) along with helmert transformation (https://proj4.org/operations/transformations/helmert.html#examples) and got something like this

`+proj=pipeline
+step +proj=helmert +convention=coordinate_frame +x=0 +y=0 +theta=0 +scale=1
+step +proj=lcc +lat_1=35.46666666666667 +lat_2=34.03333333333333 +lat_0=33.5 +lon_0=-118 +x_0=2000000.0001016 +y_0=500000.0001016001 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs`

Here is my code in python (simplified case):

    `proj4_4326 = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
    proj4_2229 = "+proj=lcc +lat_1=35.46666666666667 +lat_2=34.03333333333333 +lat_0=33.5 +lon_0=-118 +x_0=2000000.0001016 +y_0=500000.0001016001 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs"
    proj4_helmert = "+proj=helmert +convention=coordinate_frame +x=0 +y=0 +theta=0 +scale=1"
    srs_4326 = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs_4326.ImportFromProj4(proj4_4326)
    srs_2229 = osr.SpatialReference()
    srs_2229.ImportFromProj4("+proj=pipeline +step {} +step {}".format(proj4_helmert, proj4_2229))
    global_coords_calculated = convert_coordinates_cs(6427213.13, 1984970.215, srs_2229, srs_4326)
    print global_coords_calculated`

But it ends up with error `TypeError: in method 'Geometry_Transform', argument 2 of type 'OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow *`. I've tried to google it and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572190/gdal-reprojection-error-in-method-geometry-transform-argument-2-of-type-osr
Seems that it means that some library is missing, but I've installed pyproj along with GDAL.
I am using virtualenv, python2 and macOS.

Comment: What versions of PROJ and GDAL are you using? AFAIK the current GDAL release is not yet ready for helmert transformations. I'm not sure about pyproj.

Comment: Proj = 5.2.0
GDAL = 2.3.2
I've even removed pyproj. It's latest version was released at the beginning of 2016, is is definitely outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDAL 2.3.2 can not use the new pipeline transformation in PROJ.5.

According to http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Early-GDAL-2-4-0-release-td5387216.html, you may have to wait for GDAL 2.5.0, to be released April/May 2019.

Until then, you can use those transformations only in `cs2cs` and the new `cct`.